# Database-Layout for i18n WITH multiple content-types

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel-4

First of all: I did do a search, but I didn't find anything that would help me with my specific problem.

The thing is, I'm building my very own CMS-System and while I do it for myself and to learn and extend my programming skills to the web I want to do it the right way from the beginning.

Goals:

A multilingual site built upon "nodes" where the content may be a static page, a blog, a gallery... you name it. I approached this in good old OOP.

The thing is, that I'm not quite sure on what's the best way to build the Database-Scheme, especially performance wise. I mean, I want to keep it as extensible as possible, yet as fast as possible. (basically no unnecessary queries)

I use a NODE-Table that consists of this:

```
id | parent_id | level/depth | name (human identifier)
```

then I have a tree that saves all the different paths from each node to its descendants

```
id | ancestor | descendant
```

(in case you wonder why I redundantly save the parent_id on the node as well-it's for automatic building the tree!)

So, to map the content to a node I have this mapper:

```
id | node_id | language_id | type_id | content_id | slug
```

where the type_id references a type such as "Page" or "Blog", "Gallery" and content_id would reference the actual "Page" or "Blog" in their respective tables. (A blog would then have a "blog_posts" table where they reference a specific blog etc.)

So for each node and language combination I could specify a different type (so the node with id 3 could be a blog or a static page, only depending on the language and could be accessible under "/en/I-am-a-blog" or "/de/hallo-welt")

But I'm not too sure about that approach. I could save the slugs to the content-tables themselves (unnecessary).

Other than that I could even add another layer of abstraction with a "content"-table between the actual content and the mapper, which would hold ALL content. But I'm not too sure on what compromise to make between extensibility and performance.

But as said, I'm here to ask what you would do in my position :)

I really hope this is no duplicate I overlooked and I did everything according to the rules of this community.

Have a wonderful day!

Cheers,
Nalrakesh

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a wonderful PHP Localization Class bundle that is setup for both local file and DB, user's preference.

The PHP Class references the content at three simple levels "Container", "Section", and "Element".

The download bundle includes an sql script for creating the il8n Localization schema in a MySQL DB. Why not leverage a regulated standard?. Even if you want to use a different DB Type you would still be able to at least reference the schema for how you should create your own.

I hope this helps.

Link: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2444-PHP-Get-internationalized-texts-from-databases-or-XML.html#download

Comment: Thank you, but I wanna go with my own implementation. I mean how everything works together is already set :)